# how to find dependent packages in caktin

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

is there way to get list of the depend package as we used rospack depend, for catkin?

```
k-okada@kokada-t430s:/opt/ros/hydro/share/roslang$ rospack depends roslanag
[rospack] Error: no such package roslanag
k-okada@kokada-t430s:/opt/ros/hydro/share/roslang$ rospack depends-on roslanag
[rospack] Warning: no such package roslanag
```

UPDATE:

Original question is invalid, rospack depend should work.

```
$ rospack depends roslang
catkin
genmsg
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/137041/how-to-find-dependent-packages-in-caktin/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2014-03-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the roslanag package does not exist. There is roslang package without 'a' in /opt/ros/hydro/share/,is this the one you are  looking for?  if it is ,you can try "rospack depends roslang"

---

Originally posted by [Yuichi Chu](https://answers.ros.org/users/9086/yuichi-chu/) with karma: 148 on 2014-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2014-03-07**:
no, I'd like to find  roslang depends on these two package, (sorry that using roslang is not a good example)

```
<run_depend>catkin</run_depend>
<run_depend>genmsg</run_depend>
```

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-03-07**:
As the answer suggests `rospack depends roslang` will output the dependencies of the `roslang` package: `catkin` and `genmsg`

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2014-03-07**:
it works, I was confused when I pose original question. maybe forget to source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash or something. I'm very sorry to bother you.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-03-07**:
No worries - that is what this platform is all about. And in the future someone else might find the question and answer helpful.